# Custom domain mapping in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, subdomain, domain-mapping

I am creating a cloud based application in codeigniter/php.

I have a functionality where user can have their website at user.myapp.com and it works (with subdomain and model binding).

I now want to go one step further, and allow users to add their own custom domain names. So their website will be reachable at user-domain.com rather than (or as well as) user.myapp.com.

I want to understand how to do this. I'm using codeigniter framework which is based on php and apache.

What kind of server do I need? Can I use shared hosting? What configs do I need to do in order for this to work? What DNS record the user must create to put things together?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.